# Why LTspice is showing singular matrix error in the following inverter circuit?

Tags: inverter, ltspice, wireless-charging

[image: Inverter circuit followed by an air core transformer]
While simulating this circuit I am getting an error of singular matrix. Any advice?

Comment: Try making the schematic more compact hence detail will become bigger (when posted here) and quite possibly easier to read.

Comment: Whenever you ask a question about an error message (on any computer related topic), always quote the exact message. Don't give it your own interpretation, don't skip parts because you think it is unimportant. A screenshot can be helpful, but to be able to search for the message it is vital to include it in typed text.

Comment: No negative supply on U4/U6?

Comment: You also have a "floating" supply on U3 and U4.

Answer (score 3):

As Spehro says, there is no negative supply on U4 and U6.

Furthermore,

- The bottom of L1 must NOT be grounded, because activating M3 creates a dead short from Vcc, and M4 does nothing.
- You are supplying signal for U3 and U4 from a ground reference, which will be significantly offset from U3/U4 supply references. (Research [isolated MOSFET drivers](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=isolated+mosfet+driver).)
- Also note a [magnetic coupling coefficient](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/lt-journal/LTMag-V16N3-23-LTspice_Transformers-MikeEngelhardt.pdf) of 0.0428 is extremely low. To quote this article,

> Leakage inductance can cause undesired voltage spikes or ringing which can lead to a requirement for snubbing circuits and their associated energy losses.
> For an initial simulation, it’s easier and often sufficient to ignore leakage inductance by setting the mutual coupling coefficient to 1.

Also,

> You may want to simulate the effects of leakage inductance in order to  consider snubber designs or work out the commutation timing of a resonantly
> switched converter. There are two ways to add leakage inductance to your model. You can either put extra inductors in series with the leads of the winding inductors — a very direct approach — or use a mutual coupling coefficient of less than one. The leakage inductance, \$L_{LEAK}\$, can be related to the
> winding inductance \$L\$ and coupling coefficient \$K\$ by the equation:
> \$L_{LEAK} = L \cdot (1 – K^2)\$. If K is close to 1, the two methods
> are electrically equivalent.

Comment: With a \$k\$ value of 0.0428, this is implying that 99.8% of your 220.2uH primary coil is leakage inductance - inductance with no magnetic coupling to L2. See [this link](http://www.w0qe.com/Technical_Topics/coupling_between_coils.html) for calculating mutual inductance at distances.

Answer (score 0):

Your parts are so far apart on your schematic that the text is tiny and impossible to read.
[image: Mosfet drivers]